# Google Play Billing queryPurchasesAsync returns empty subscriptions list while there is an active subscription

Tags: android, android-billing, play-billing-library, google-play-billing

The Google Play Billing Library is returning an empty list of subscriptions when querying through the `queryPurchasesAsync` method while in fact there *is* an active subscription. From the [documentation of queryPurchasesAsync](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#queryPurchasesAsync(com.android.billingclient.api.QueryPurchasesParams,%20com.android.billingclient.api.PurchasesResponseListener)):

> Only active subscriptions and non-consumed one-time purchases are returned. This method uses a cache of Google Play Store app without initiating a network request.

I tried emptying the Play Store cache, but still an empty list is returned.

I'm using the Play Billing Library 6.0.1. Here's my relevant code:

```
private BillingClient billingClient;
private final Set<Purchase> purchases;
boolean billingClientConnected;

public static BillingManager getInstance(Activity activity) {
    if (billingManager == null) {
        billingManager = new BillingManager(activity);
    }
    return billingManager;
}

public BillingManager(Activity activity) {
    productList = new ArrayList<>();
    purchases = new HashSet<>();
    init(activity);
}

private void init(Activity activity) {

    // Create the billing client.
    billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(activity)
            .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
            .enablePendingPurchases()
            .build();

    startBillingClientConnection();
}

public void startBillingClientConnection() {
    if (billingClient != null) {
        billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    billingClientConnected = true;
                    // Do some other stuff..
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
                // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
                billingClientConnected = false;
            }
        });
    }
}

public void queryPurchases() {
    if (!billingClientConnected) {
        startBillingClientConnection();
    } else {
        QueryPurchasesParams subsPurchasesParams = QueryPurchasesParams.newBuilder()
                .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
                .build();
        billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(subsPurchasesParams, 
            new PurchasesResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onQueryPurchasesResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult,
                                                 @NonNull List<Purchase> purchaseList) {
                    if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                        // Here I get an empty list.                    
                        // Handle all purchases that were successfully queried.
                        for (Purchase purchase : purchaseList) {
                            handlePurchase(purchase);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like it might have to do with the logged in accounts on the Play Store - if you have multiple accounts there, try logging out the accounts you're not testing with and see if that helps. Not really a sustainable solution, since users might also be logged in with multiple Google accounts, but this seems to at least get to the root of the issue